# I want to disable controls inside the Silverlight usercontrol from an event inside the asp.net usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, javascript, silverlight

I have an ASP.NET usercontrol inside which I am enbedding the Silverlight usercontrol. I have two events in the asp.net usercontrol - EDit and View . In the view mode I want all the controls on the Silverlight side to be disabled . So, How can I disable the controls from my asp.net code.
Thanks

Comment: You can use javascript check out this blog [Silverlight communication](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ-based code:

```
parentControl.Controls.Foreach(c => c.Enabled = false);
```